# Change bg color of divs with 2 lowest innerText values (values are created randomly)

Tags: javascript, html, dom

First of all, I apologize if this is a stupid question, I'm fairly new to JavaScript and have been experimenting and trying to do this for several days now.

Let's say I have 6 train cars (divs) with their respective id's.

```
<div class="train">
    <div class="car" id = "car1">a</div>
    <div class="car" id = "car2">b</div>
    <div class="car" id = "car3">b</div>
    <div class="car" id = "car4">b</div>
    <div class="car" id = "car5">b</div>
    <div class="car" id = "car6">b</div>
</div>
```

My script generates innerText of these divs using random numbers from 0 to 160 (number of passengers in each respective train car).
I want to change the background color of 2 cars with the least amount of passengers.

First, I create a new Object of trainCar to contain information about the number of passengers and the car id.

```
var passengers = document.querySelectorAll(".car");
var trainCar = {};

for (let i = 0; i <= passengers.length-1; i++) {
    passengers[i].innerHTML = getRandomNumber(); 
    trainCar[i] = {
        numberOfPassengers: passengers[i].innerHTML,
        carId: passengers[i].id,
    }
}
```

This creates multiple objects within my main object trainCar (this is the console.log):

```
{0: {…}, 1: {…}, 2: {…}, 3: {…}, 4: {…}, 5: {…}}
0: {numberOfPassengers: "17", carId: "car1"}
1: {numberOfPassengers: "87", carId: "car2"}
2: {numberOfPassengers: "106", carId: "car3"}
3: {numberOfPassengers: "157", carId: "car4"}
4: {numberOfPassengers: "154", carId: "car5"}
5: {numberOfPassengers: "56", carId: "car6"}
```

So this is where I'm stuck. I can change background color of one of the cars using:
`document.getElementById(trainCar[2].carId).style="background-color: grey";`
but I have no idea how to match the lowest value of innerHTML with the corresponding id and change this id's background (let alone the lowest two).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep track of the 2 min values in your for loop. You will also need to keep track of the ids that correspond to those min values. You can see a working snippet here below:

```js
var passengers = document.querySelectorAll(".car");
var trainCar = {};

let min = Infinity;
let min2 = Infinity;
let minId, min2Id;

for (let i = 0; i <= passengers.length-1; i++) {
    const value = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100); 
    if(value < min){
      min2 = min;
      min2Id = minId;
      min = value;
      minId = i;
    } else if (value < min2){
      min2 = value;
      min2Id = i;
    }
    passengers[i].innerHTML = value;
    trainCar[i] = {
        numberOfPassengers: value,
        carId: passengers[i].id,
    }
}

passengers[minId].style.backgroundColor = 'grey';
passengers[min2Id].style.backgroundColor = 'grey';
```

```html
<div class="train">
    <div class="car" id = "car1">a</div>
    <div class="car" id = "car2">b</div>
    <div class="car" id = "car3">b</div>
    <div class="car" id = "car4">b</div>
    <div class="car" id = "car5">b</div>
    <div class="car" id = "car6">b</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, that worked. I was doing it completely the wrong way :) Thank you for the elegant solution, sir. However, I don't fully understand the `min2Id = i;` part. Why is that necessary?

Comment: `min` and `min2` are used to store the 2 smallest values, while `minId` and `min2Id` are used to store the index of the corresponding divs. Whenever you check for a new value, you have 3 cases:
1. the value is bigger than your 2 min values, so you just ignore it.
2. the value is smaller than both your min values, in this case this become your new min, and the old min become your min2.
3. The value is bigger than min, but smaller than min2, in this case min stays the same, and the value become your new min2. `min2Id=i` will store the index of this new div